# How to change the position of the filters in product page or Layered navigation

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter

**Hi,**

I need to change the layer navigation position as shown in below image the **Manufacturer** first and **Category** to second. But i can't find how to change these.

[image]

The **Category** must come at **second position** how to position it ?

**Thanks in Advance :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

The filters in the layered navigation are being built in this file:

First, replace the below code if it works then use it to plugin and write logic.

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/FilterList.php**

```
public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
    {
        if (!count($this->filters)) {
            $this->filters = [
                $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
            ];
            foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
                $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
            }
        }
        $data = array_shift($this->filters);
        $this->filters[]=  $data;
        return $this->filters;
    }
```

With a custom plugin afterGetFilters you should be able to check if the first item in the array is instance of **Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category**. If so, place it at the end of the array before returning the result.

> Plugin

Create custom Module and create below files

> **File**:Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

        <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
            <plugin name="Custom_filter" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterList" sortOrder="120"/>
        </type>

</config>
```

> **File**:-Vendor/Module/Model/Layer/FilterList.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Layer;

class FilterList {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer
     * @param array|Filter\AbstractFilter[]
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetFilters(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer 
    ) {

        if (!count($this->filters)) {
            $this->filters = [
                $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
            ];
            foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
                $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
            }
        }
        $data = array_shift($this->filters);
        $this->filters[]=  $data;
        return $this->filters;
      }

}
```

> Run CLI commands

```
 bin/magento setup:upgrade
 bin/magento setup:di:compile
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 bin/magento cache:clean
 bin/magento cache:flush
```

And check I hope this will help you.

Comment: I had not created plugin till now can you give me ideas and how to di it @Devidas

Comment: What is the instace of you mentioning here

Comment: first replace above function in this file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/FilterList.php

Comment: if it works then I guide you on how to create a plugin

Comment: OK wait I will check and update you

Comment: Yes Bro @devidas it works

Comment: Yes the manufacturer comes first and can you hoe to create plugin @Devidas

Comment: check this links https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

Comment: read line by line so you can learn plugin concept

Comment: I will update my code can you check it @Devidas

Comment: please give me some time i will update my answer using plugin

Comment: OK bro take your time @Devidas

Comment: Hey @Sabareesh check the updated answer

Comment: For what we are mentioning SortOrder in di.xml @Devidas bro

Comment: you can remove it

Comment: ok Thank you, I worked well bro