# Magento 2.3.4 - How to create filter by product rating in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, magento2.3.4, ratings

I want to have a filter by product rating in layered navigation. Regarding this, I found a solution [Magento 2 : Rating Filter in Layered Navigation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102722/magento-2-rating-filter-in-layered-navigation). This is working fine if you modify vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList.php in core folder(vendor folder). But I'm not able to override vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList.php from app/code. Please share if anybody has any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Create a module and add the below files. Create plugin to override  `FilterList.php`

> **File**:- Vendor/Module/Model/Layer/Filter/Rating.php

This file code available here [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102722/magento-2-rating-filter-in-layered-navigation)

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as CategoryModel;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory as CategoryModelFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Rating extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter
{

    protected $_categoryId;
    protected $_appliedCategory;
    protected $_escaper;
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    private $dataProvider;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($filterItemFactory, $storeManager, $layer, $itemDataBuilder, $data);
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->_requestVar = 'rat';
    }

    public function getResetValue()
    {
        return $this->dataProvider->getResetValue();
    }

    public function apply(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {

        $filter = $request->getParam($this->getRequestVar());
        if (!$filter) {
            return $this;
        }
        $filter = explode('-', $filter);
        list($from, $to) = $filter;
         $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('rova'=> 'rating_option_vote_aggregated'),'e.entity_id =rova.entity_pk_value',array("percent"))
        ->where("rova.percent between ".$from." and ".$to)
        ->group('e.entity_id'); 
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return __('Rating');
    }

    protected function _getItemsData()
    {

        $facets = array(
            '0-20'=>'1 Start',
            '21-40'=>'2 Start',
            '41-60'=>'3 Start',
            '61-80'=>'4 Start',
            '81-100'=>'5 Start'
            );
     $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $data = [];
        if (count($facets) > 1) { // two range minimum
            $i=1;
            foreach ($facets as $key => $label) {
               $count=$this->prepareData($key,$collection,$i);
               $i++;
               $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                    $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($label),
                    $key,
                    $count
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
    }

    private function prepareData($filter,$collection,$i)
    {
       $filter = explode('-', $filter);
        list($from, $to) = $filter;

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('rova'.$i=> 'rating_option_vote_aggregated'),'e.entity_id =rova'.$i.'.entity_pk_value',array("percent"))
        ->where("rova".$i.".percent between ".$from." and ".$to)
        ->group('e.entity_id'); 
        return $collection->getSize();
    }
}
```

> **File**:- Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <plugin name="rating-filter-category-navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\FilterList" />
    </type>

</config>
```

> **File**:- Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/FilterList.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

class FilterList
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_layer;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_stockResource;

    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Resource\Stock\Status $stockResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_stockResource = $stockResource;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

   public function afterGetFilters(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer 
) {

    if (!count($this->filters)) {
        $this->filters = [
            $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
        ];
        foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
            $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
        }
    }
    $data = array_shift($this->filters);
    $this->filters[]=  $data;
    return $this->filters;
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you...!

Comment: Yes that's the way I took. But I stuck in the following function
public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
    {

    }

Here I'm not able to get $this->filterableAttributes->getList() since it's a interface. How to get that value in app/code/custom_module

Comment: check this ans https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312680/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-filters-in-product-page-or-layered-navigation/312683?noredirect=1#comment449245_312683

Comment: and check I have the update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Devidas for taking time for looking into it. I'm almost there. I followed the link you added in the comment https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312680/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-filters-in-product-page-or-layered-navigation/312683?noredirect=1#comment449245_312683. But I'm getting 500 server error. I checked no other PHP error is there in the code. Can you please tell me apart from the function what should I add in the class. It's a bit more to ask, but if you could tell me it'll be very helpful for me.